# How can I compute the differential of a projective morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, projective-geometry

I want to understand how to compute the differential of a projective morphism of schemes. For example, consider the projective morphism
$$
\begin{matrix}
& \textbf{Proj} \left(\frac{\mathbb{C}[s,t][x,y,z]}{x^3 + y^3 + s(x^2y + z^3) + t(xyz)} \right) \\
& \downarrow \pi \\
& \textbf{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[s,t])
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Do you mean the global sections of the cotangent sheaf of this space over the bottom?

Comment: No. That may be interesting though